# How can it be explained the name of a car Range Rover?

Tags: names

How can it be explained the name of a car Range Rover? What assassinations does the name of it have? thanks

Comment: "Assassination" is the murder of a prominent person for political purposes. I am not aware of any assassinations where someone killed an enemy leader by running him down with a Range Rover. :-)

Comment: @Jay [Three drug dealers "assassinated" while *in* a Range Rover](https://www.vice.com/en_uk/article/bernard-omahoney-why-im-finally-telling-the-truth-about-the-britains-most-notorious-gangland-murder).  Best I could do.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to assume you mean "associations" not "assassinations", but let's cover a few things first.

> 1. Car names are not great examples of exact english.

They contain made up words, words only used because they sound good, and random numbers.

So "Range Rovers" are meant to be all time 4 wheel drive vehicles that can do decently in offroading.

A "range" can be a series of mountains (a "mountain range"), or a large area of open plains. So think of large areas of open wilderness.

And to "rove" means to travel and wander constantly without a fixed destination. And so a:

> Range Rover

Is meant to be a car that you can "rove" over "ranges", in essence, to explore and do outdoor activities, and that is what the name is maent to invoke.

Comment: In some fields, such as the law, technical writing, or some newspapers, the phrase *Range Rovers* is incorrect.  In trademark law, trademarks are defined to be **adjectives that modify nouns**, so *Range Rover vehicles*, *Toyota Celica sports cars*, and *Kleenex tissues* are correct.   You cannot have *Xeroxes*, *Nikons* or *Sonys*, only Xerox *photocopiers*, Nikon *cameras* or Sony *products*, in that world.  Ads say "Jeep vehicles", or "Band-aid brand", to avoid [**trademark dilution** (genericide)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark).